# The deleteRow method is deprecated. Is there an alternative to deleting a row in Google Sheets App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I click the 'Execution Hints' for a function where I was using the deleteRow method, a message pops up saying:

> Method Sheet.deleteRows is deprecated.

There is an Expand button which states:

> The method has been marked as deprecated which means that the feature should be avoided and may be removed in the future. Consider using an alternative solution.

The documentation doesn't mention that this is deprecated and so provides no alternative solution. Is there a different method for deleting a row in Google Sheets App Script?

Comment: Don't think that it's deprecated, else the documentation likely would list it as deprecated... and even if, unless the documentation would reflect that, that doesn't help much.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, could you please share your code?

Comment: What's your runtime? V8? View> show manifest file>appsscript.json<see runtime:

Comment: I’m now unable to recreate this message. I haven’t changed my code at all since last night but the Execution Hint is greyed out (lightbulb next to the function selector).